# Adding startup script to systemd without using systemctl

Tags: linux, systemd, init, systemctl, rc

I am trying to add a startup python script to a Linux OS with systemd, where I have to set the script up from another Linux OS which is init based.

```
|   Running OS     |                        |   OS to be installed |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[init based Linux ] -- add startup script --> [systemd based Linux]
```

This script would be used to add some custom configuration on the very first bootup after installation, and it's essential for me to do all configuration before the terminal is available.

As the startup script should run before I can execute any commands, I'm not able to use systemctl for this purpose.

In previous cases I've used the rc.local file for similar problems, but in the current case it doesn't seem to work (or I'm missing something).

**Are there any other alternative solutions for this problem?**

Comment: if all you can do is copy files, make a service file that will ExecStart your script, add it to /etc/systemd/system and create a sym link to it in /etc/systemd/system/multi-target-user-wants/ (or whatever the target should be). Next boot it should run.

Comment: if I understand correctly you only want this to run once on the first boot only and not on subsequent boots? if so at the end of the script you can touch a file that would signify the script has run and at the start you can just exit if that file exists. you can do that in many different ways, I just mention the file touching as an example